# Robots.txt not found by Google in PHP app engine

Tags: php, google-app-engine, yaml, robots.txt

It appears my `robots.txt` file is not being found by Googlebot as I keep receiving 404 errors on `Stack Logger`.

My app is structured like so:

```
/www
    - index.html
    - sendMessage.php
app.yaml
robots.txt
```

Here's my `app.yaml` file:

```
runtime: php55
service: default
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
automatic_scaling:
   min_idle_instances: 1
instance_class: F4_1G

handlers:
- url: /sendMessage.php
  script: sendMessage.php
  secure: always 

- url: /
 static_files: www/index.html
 upload: www/index.html
 secure: always

- url: /robots.txt
  static_files: robots.txt
  upload: robots.txt

- url: /(.*)
static_files: www/\1
upload: www/(.*)
secure: always
```

And then my `robots.txt` file is:

```
# Rule 1
User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /nogooglebot/

# Rule 2
User-agent: *
Allow: /
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Is the 404 for the `/robots.txt` path itself? Can you show the log entry?

Comment: I have set up a HelloWorld application with your same architecture and calling the /robots.txt URL yields the robots.txt file. Can you provide more details?